# Ajax response comparison with string

Tags: ajax

In the below example my Ajax response is coming as 'success'[ type is string], and I am comparing the 'success' [type is string]. Then why does the control not enter into the if condition?

```
$.ajax({
        url: "controller.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: { loginData : $("#loginForm").serialize()},
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (response) {
            if(response=='success') // response coming as is 'success'
            {  
                window.open('www.google.com');
            }
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            /* error handling code*/
        }
});
```

Comment: How do you know what the value of `response` is?

Comment: Why not use the actual response status to determine success or error? You might as well just return an empty 200 response for success and not bother actually comparing the response body

Comment: `console.log(escape(response));` I bet it is more than the word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing data as plain text. I recommend passing data as JSON because it's easier to catch the response from the server.

Also, you are using a variable that will contain more variables (the form inputs) in `data: { loginData : $("#loginForm").serialize()}`. I recommend you using `.serializeArray()` to send data as JSON variables that you can catch in the server script.

So:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "controller.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: $("#loginForm").serializeArray(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
    if(response["success"]) {
        window.open('www.google.com');
    }
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
    // error handling code
    }
});
```

And in `controller.php`:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['input'])) { // use your input's name instead
    $response['success'] = true;
} else {
    $response['success'] = false;
}

header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

And also, with this last code snippet you can pass more than "success" (simply because you're using an array). Eg:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['input'])) { // use your input's name instead
    $response['success'] = true;
    $response['open'] = 'www.google.com';
} else {
    $response['success'] = false;
}

header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: OP specifically has `dataType: "text"` which is **not** *"HTML text"*